# Why does C++ need the scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++, operators, language-design, scope-resolution

(I know what the scope resolution operator does, and how and when to use it.)

Why does C++ have the `::` operator, instead of using the `.` operator for this purpose? Java doesn't have a separate operator, and works fine. Is there some difference between C++ and Java that means C++ requires a separate operator in order to be parsable?

My only guess is that `::` is needed for precedence reasons, but I can't think why it needs to have higher precedence than, say, `.`. The only situation I can think it would is so that something like

```
a.b::c;
```

would be parsed as

```
a.(b::c);
```

, but I can't think of any situation in which syntax like this would be legal anyway.

Maybe it's just a case of "they do different things, so they might as well look different".  But that doesn't explain why `::` has higher precedence than `.`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why C++ doesn't use `.` where it uses `::`, is because this is how the language is defined. One plausible reason could be, to refer to the global namespace using the syntax `::a` as shown below:

```
int a = 10;
namespace M
{
    int a = 20;
    namespace N
    {
           int a = 30;
           void f()
           {
              int x = a; //a refers to the name inside N, same as M::N::a
              int y = M::a; //M::a refers to the name inside M
              int z = ::a; //::a refers to the name in the global namespace

              std::cout<< x <<","<< y <<","<< z <<std::endl; //30,20,10
           }
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/sp28n)

I don't know how Java solves this. I don't even know if in Java there is global namespace. In C#, you refer to global name using the syntax `global::a`, which means even C# has `::` operator.

---

> but I can't think of any situation in which syntax like this would be legal anyway.

Who said syntax like `a.b::c` is not legal?

Consider these classes:

```
struct A
{
    void f() { std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : A
{
    void f(int) { std::cout << "B::f(int)" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now see this ([ideone](http://ideone.com/CzI0c)):

```
B b;
b.f(10); //ok
b.f();   //error - as the function is hidden
```

`b.f()` cannot be called like that, as the function is hidden, and the GCC gives this error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘B::f()’
```

In order to call `b.f()` (or rather `A::f()`), you need scope resolution operator:

```
b.A::f(); //ok - explicitly selecting the hidden function using scope resolution
```

[Demo at ideone](http://ideone.com/L7LBS)

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can't just say `b.A.f` instead of `b.A::f`. If `A` is a typename instead of a variable or function, then using `.` could easily have meant `scope resolution` instead of the regular meaning.

Comment: You could still just say `.a` to mean the global one, and `M.a` to mean the one in the `M` namespace.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The syntax `.a` looks awkward when the syntax `.` is mostly used for *member-of* or something.

Comment: Maybe, but if you'd been looking at it for 10 years it wouldn't. Personally, `::` looks more awkward even after 10 years.

Comment: The assumption I made about `a.b::c` not being sensible is what was causing my confusion. Accepted this answer because I think it's as good as the others but also points out my mistake.

Comment: There is no global namespace in Java because everything is inside one class or another.

Comment: Early versions of C++ changed from `.` to `::` for some reason, and as namespaces were not implemented until much later than that change it is unlikely that this is the motivation.

Comment: `I don't know how Java solves this.` FWIW, the D language uses syntax similar to Java and it solves it just by prefixing a dot to the name. http://dlang.org/spec/module.html#module_scope_operators This is essentially what @NicolBolas discussed earlier.

Comment: `a.(A.f)()` would be ok for me.

Answer (score 36):

Because someone in the C++ standards committee thought that it was a good idea to allow this code to work:

```
struct foo
{
  int blah;
};

struct thingy
{
  int data;
};

struct bar : public foo
{
  thingy foo;
};

int main()
{
  bar test;
  test.foo.data = 5;
  test.foo::blah = 10;
  return 0;
}
```

Basically, it allows a member variable and a derived class type to have the same name. I have *no idea* what someone was smoking when they thought that this was important. But there it is.

When the compiler sees `.`, it knows that the thing to the left must be an object. When it sees `::`, it must be a typename or namespace (or nothing, indicating the global namespace). That's how it resolves this ambiguity.

Comment: Why can't you write `test.foo.blah = 10`? Or `test.base.blah = 10` where `base` is a keyword?

Comment: @Nawaz: Because introducing a keyword is a *lot* harder than introducing an operator. And `test.foo.blah` is ambiguous; is it the base-class's `blah` or the `thingy` member's `blah`? Java (as I understand it) gets around this by stating that it's always the member; you can only get at base class member variables by casting the type.

Comment: @Nawaz: Because this would not give any way of specifying *which* `base` you wanted to use.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It maybe harder from compiler author perspective, but from programmers perspective `base.blah` is lot easier (and less awkward).

Comment: @Nawaz: Unless of course your code ever used the identifier `base` anywhere. Which is entirely possible. Keywording things isn't hard because of the compiler; it's hard because it makes things that *used* those keywords break. Even a context-specific keyword means you can't have a type named `base`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: C++ has introduced many *`new`* keywords (pun unintended) :  `new`, `delete`, `bool`, etc. Why not `base`? :|

Comment: @Nawaz: Let's also not forget that `base` isn't going to help you with multiple inheritance.

Comment: NicolBolas: Haha. I knew that you would bring that point (which I was waiting for :D). Anyway, it means your answer isn't complete in itself, as it *technically* depends on another feature of C++ called multiple inheritance. But I also note that you commented on @dasblinkenlight's answer, saying : "*Technically that's not about multiple inheritance. [..]*".... :D

Comment: @Nawaz: What? You're suggesting a *keyword*, which isn't a working suggestion because of multiple inheritance. *You* brought it up; it had nothing to do with what I or the OP said. The OP is asking why there is a *difference* between member field selection and scope selection. He's asking why there is special syntax to state one vs. the other; `.base` is no better in this regard than `::`. He's asking why they *can't* be the same. And I answered that.

Comment: `test.(foo.blah) = 10` would be ok for me.

Comment: @anton_rh would it look up `foo` in the local scope or in `bar` scope? would it be the same as `test.*(&foo.blah) = 10` or not?

Answer (score 10):

> Why does C++ have the :: operator, instead of using the . operator for this purpose?

The reason is given by Stroustrup himself:

> In C with Classes, a dot was used to express membership of a class as well as expressing selection of a member of a particular object.
>
> This had been the cause of some minor confusion and could also be used to construct ambiguous examples. To alleviate this, `::` was introduced to mean membership of class and `.` was retained exclusively for membership of object

(Bjarne Stroustrup [*A History of C++: 1979−1991*](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf) page 21 - § 3.3.1)

Moreover it's true that

> they do different things, so they might as well look different

indeed

> In `N::m` neither `N` nor `m` are expressions with values; `N` and `m` are names known to the compiler and `::` performs a (compile time) scope resolution rather than an expression evaluation. One could imagine allowing overloading of x::y where x is an object rather than a namespace or a class, but that would - contrary to first appearances - involve introducing new syntax (to allow `expr::expr`). It is not obvious what benefits such a complication would bring.
>
> Operator `.` (dot) could in principle be overloaded using the same technique as used for `->`.

(Bjarne Stroustrup's [C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot))

Answer (score 9):

Unlike Java, C++ has multiple inheritance. Here is one example where scope resolution of the kind you're talking about becomes important:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct a
{
    int x;
};
struct b
{
    int x;
};
struct c : public a, public b
{
    ::a a;
    ::b b;
};
int main() {
    c v;
    v.a::x = 5;
    v.a.x = 55;
    v.b::x = 6;
    v.b.x = 66;
    cout << v.a::x << " " << v.b::x << endl;
    cout << v.a.x << " " << v.b.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically that's not about multiple inheritance. It's about being able to name your variables the same names as your derived classes.

Comment: C++ did not have multiple inheritance when the `::` operator was introduced.  See the [Cfront E manual, page 22 (25 in the pdf)](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_e/doc/ReferenceManual.pdf) - `::` in use, but no sign of multiple inheritance in the description of classes.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer the final bit of the question about operator precedence:

```
class A {
public:
  char A;
};

class B : public A {
public:
  double A;
};

int main(int c, char** v)
{
  B myB;
  myB.A = 7.89;
  myB.A::A = 'a';
  // On the line above a hypothetical myB.A.A
  // syntax would parse as (myB.A).A and since
  // (myB.A) is of type double you get (double).A in the
  // next step. Of course the '.' operator has no
  // meaning for doubles so it causes a syntax error. 
  // For this reason a different operator that binds
  // more strongly than '.' is needed.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that a parser couldn't simply wait and check the next token to see if it's a `.` before deciding on the ambiguity?

Comment: No, certainly such a parser could be written. The intermediate result would be ambiguous and when the next token comes in you can assume that the user didn't mean to make a syntax error. So it isn't strictly necessary in that sense, but the '::' operator is useful elsewhere and C++ parser authors have enough problems already.   :)

Comment: @nolandda The first version of C++, "Cpre" had a working parser that used `.` for scope resolution (See source code of Cfront, which was written to be compiled by Cpre: http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_e/src/cfront.pdf).  Having figured out how to do it, I doubt Stroustrup would have then backed down from doing it again when he reimplemented the language.  I therefore don't think the technical difficulty of using it was part of the reason.

Answer (score 3):

I always assumed C++ dot/:: usage was a style choice, to make code easier to read. As the OP writes "they do different things, so should look different."

Coming from C++, long ago, to C#, I found using only dots confusing. I was used to seeing `A::doStuff();` `B.doStuff();`, and knowing the first is a regular function, in a namespace, and the second is a member function on instance B.

C++ is maybe my fifth language, after Basic, assembly, Pascal and Fortran, so I don't think it's first language syndrome, and I'm more a C# programmer now. But, IMHO, if you've used both, C++-style double-colon for namespaces reads better. I feel like Java/C# chose dots for both to (successfully) ease the front of the learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

Scope resolution operator(::) is used to define a function outside a class or when we want to use a global variable but also has a local variable with same name.