# I seem to have some misconceptions about `static` in C++

Tags: c++, static

I seem to have some misconceptions about how the `static` keyword works in C++; specifically, I need to understand the problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    int a;

    A(int ain) : a(ain) { }
    A() : a(1) { }

    static A getA()
    {
        return A(2);
    }
};

struct B
{
    static A a = A::getA();
};


int main() {
    std::cout << B::a.a << std::endl;
}
```

Had `static` worked as I expected it to, the above code sample would have printed `2` and exited normally - instead, I get the following compiler error message:

```
g++    -c -o syntax.o syntax.cpp
syntax.cpp:17:21: error: ‘A::getA()’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
     static A a = A::getA();
                     ^
syntax.cpp:17:26: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
     static A a = A::getA();
                          ^
syntax.cpp:17:26: error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type ‘A’
syntax.cpp:17:26: error: initializer invalid for static member with constructor
syntax.cpp:17:26: error: (an out of class initialization is required)
syntax.cpp:17:26: error: ‘B::a’ cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared
make: *** [syntax.o] Error 1
```

I read the error messages and I realize that there's something about `static` that I haven't understood, but I find it hard to pinpoint *what*. It's probably because I've done a fair amount of work in languages like Java and C#, which also have the `static` keyword but where it, apparently, works differently.

Will someone please explain to me why the above code is invalid?

Comment: For starters, B has no `getA()` method. The line `std::cout << B.getA().a << std::endl;` can never compile. Secondly, `A.getA();` should be `A::getA();`.

Comment: @executifs: Sorry, it seems I was a little too eager to provide something runnable to note the problems in my main method. I've updated to something more reasonable now.

Comment: And yet it still has the same errors....

Comment: @mjs: There. Now I also updated the compiler error message to what it currently gives me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STATIC MEMBER FUNCTIONS**

There are two ways of invoking a *static member function* of a given `T`, either;

- you use the [*scope resolution operator `::`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9338217/1090079), or;
- you invoke it on an instance of said type `T` using `operator.` (as if you were invoking any other *member-function* on the variable).

---

**LEGAL CONSTRUCTS**

```
struct Obj {
  static void func () { 
    /* ... */
  }
};
```

The two snippets below both call the static member function `func` within `Obj`.

```
Obj a; a.func ();
```

```
Obj::func ();
```

---

**ILLEGAL CONSTRUCTS**

```
Obj a;

Obj.func (); // illegal, `Obj` is a type and not an instance
a ::func ();  // illegal, `a` is an instance of `Obj`, not a type
```

---

---

**STATIC DATA MEMBERS**

*`static` data members* are used to declare a variables that are shared between every instance of a given type.

In the snippet provided in the question you are trying to initialize a static data member `a` of type `A` with the returned value from, the corrected, `A::getA ()`. This is not allowed since trying to initialize a `static` data member without making it `constexpr` is an illegal construct for in-class initialization.

```
struct B {
  static A a = A::getA(); // illegal, `static A a` is not `constexpr`
};
```

More about in-class initialization of *static data members* can be found here:

- [**stackoverflow.com** - C++ initialize static variables in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/c-initialize-static-variables-in-class)

Comment: Thanks - I apparently needed pointers both about accessing static members and about static data member initialization. In the end, I wanted to keep declaration and definition together, and changed `B` to `struct B { static A a() { return A::getA(); } }`. This doesn't really make sense in my example, but that just shows that my example is a simplification. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues. First, the syntax `A.getA()` is wrong: the `.` syntax is for accessing the members of an *instance*. You cannot use it to access members via a type. To use the `.` operator, you would have to create an instance of `A`, and call `getA()` via that instance. But that wouldn't make any sense. So what you need to do is call the method using the class scope resolution, i.e.  `A::getA()`. That is the first problem.

The second is that you cannot define a non-const, non-integral static member at the point of declaration. You have to separate *declaration* from *definition*. The latter should be in one translation unit only, which means putting it in a single `.cpp` file:

Header file:

```
struct B
{
    static A a; // declaration
};
```

Implementation file

```
A B::a = A::getA(); // definition
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are using the syntax to call a instance function, you need to use the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B) `::` syntax instead:

```
A::getA();
```