# why do we put :: (scope resoulation operator) before iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11

why do we put scope resolution operator before iterator whereas we do not use scope resolution operator before scores?

```
std::vector<double> scores;  
std::vector<double>::iterator pv;
```

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages - use only the relevant language tag (C++ in this case).

Comment: Because one of them is within a scope that needs resolving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C++ need the scope resolution operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338217/why-does-c-need-the-scope-resolution-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std` is a namespace.
`std::vector` is a class template in the `std` namespace, which makes `std::vector<double>` a class.
`std::vector<T>::iterator` is a nested type under `std::vector<T>`.

If you want to define an object of type `std::vector<double>`, you use:

```
std::vector<double> obj;
```

If you want to define an object of type `std::vector<double>::iterator`, you use:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator iter;
```

Comment: Vector is a class template inside std

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, thanks :) Sound like I need to take a break from computers for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You're focusing on the wrong part. The first statement defines an object named `scores`. The second statement defines an object named `pv`. Neither of those names has a `::` in front of it.

`vector` is the name of a template defined in the namespace `std`, so it is referred to as `std::vector`. `iterator` is the name of a type that is defined inside `std::vector<double>`, so it is referred to as `std::vector<double>::iterator`.

Comment: To add to this: i.e. `std::vector::iterator` is a specific iterator for the `std::vector` type. And for example `std::list` has a specific iterator at `std::list::iterator`, Etc.

Comment: I didn't understand the  accepted ans at first glance. This answer cleared my doubts. Then I read the accepted ans again. Now I can understand the accepted answer also. Simply put `vector<double>::iterator pv` declares `pv` as an iterator type variable which is inside vector class template.