# Understanding iterator/const_iterator implementation

Tags: c++, iterator

I know how to use iterators on a surface level, but I am trying to understand how iterators work in relation to a container class such as `vector`.

According to
[why do we put :: (scope resoulation operator) before iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382097/why-do-we-put-scope-resoulation-operator-before-iterator)

> `std::vector` is a class template in the std namespace, which makes `std::vector<double>` a class.
>
> `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a nested type under `std::vector<T>`

From what I understand, the class template `vector` has a member of type `iterator` which it gets from the class template in `#include <iterator>`.

This is confusing because when I look in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/ there is no `const_iterator` class template in `#include <iterator>` that I can see?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: _the class template `vector` has a member of type `iterator` which it gets from the class template in `#include <iterator>`_ — This is incorrect. The member type `iterator` of `vector` is implementation-specified. It may even be an alias for `value_type*`. There is no requirement that `std::iterator` would need to be used here.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica oh so some implementations do use the template from <iterator>? if not whats the purpose of the iterator class template in #include <iterator>

Comment: it doesn't serve much purpose at all which is why its deprecated: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator

Comment: _some implementations do use the template from `<iterator>`?_ You can check the source code of, e.g., [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx), or [Microsoft's](https://github.com/microsoft/STL). But I don't think so; as Alan pointed out, `std::iterator` is now deprecated since C++17.

Comment: so is iterator just a user defined type with the name "iterator" that is implemented in containers?

Comment: @csguy Not necessarily. As I pointed out, it may be a _type alias_ for _pointer-to-value-type_ as well. However, AFAIK, C++ Standard Library implementations define their own classes-types for container iterators.

Comment: There is nothing in the specification of `std::vector` that says `vector::iterator` or `vector::const_iterator` have any particular relationship to `std::iterator` (even in standards predating deprecation of `std::iterator`). Also, although `iterator` and `const_iterator` are types declared in the scope of `vector`, there is no requirement that `vector` have a member of either type - `iterator` and `const_iterator` are part of the interface of `std::vector` e.g. overloads of the member `begin()` returns those types, but nothing is said about how those function obtain the iterator they return.

Comment: @ThomasSablik No. a `const_iterator` gives you a `T const`. A `const iterator` gives you a `T` but you may not use the iterator to iterate, since its is const. so basically useless :D

Comment: @Peter there are no requirements for iterator and const_iterator members in container classes?

Comment: @csguy There is a requirement for a `begin` and `end` function that returns iterators (or raw pointers as that satisfies the requirements for an iterator). There is nothing that says the iterator needs to be implemented in the container.

Comment: @super is it a requirement for that iterator to have the name "iterator" hence why the `std::container<some type>::iterator` syntax works in something like `std::container<some type>::iterator i = container.begin()`

Comment: @csguy If you look at [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for example, you see that there is a list of member types.Includes `iterator`, `const_iterator` and `value_type` among others. Usually they are type aliases, `using iterator = ...;` defined inside the class.

Comment: @super hmm I see ...so containers define those member types usually with type alias for something like LegacyRandomAccessIterator which is "A pointer to an element of an array satisfies all requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator"

Comment: Yes. But `LegacyRandomAccesIterator` is an [iterator category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator). A pointer satisfies the requirements of a `LegacyRandomAccesIterator`.

Comment: Note: an example of container that doesnt have iterators is std::pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gathered information from the comments:

- `std::iterator` from `#include <iterator>` is deprecated as of C++17
- Before it was deprecated, it was *possible* for STL containers (which are implementation defined) to implemented iterators with the help of the `std::iterator` template class.
- For `vector` for example:

  > There is nothing in the specification of `std::vector` that says
  >   `vector::iterator` or `vector::const_iterator` have any particular
  >   relationship to `std::iterator` (even in standards predating deprecation
  >   of `std::iterator`). Also, although `iterator` and `const_iterator` are
  >   types declared in the scope of `vector`, there is no requirement that
  >   `vector` have a member of either type - `iterator` and `const_iterator` are
  >   part of the interface of `std::vector` e.g. overloads of the member
  >   `begin()` returns those types, but nothing is said about how those
  >   function obtain the iterator they return
- What is and isn't required in a STL container is:

  > "a begin and end function that returns
  >   iterators (or raw pointers as that satisfies the requirements for an
  >   iterator). There is nothing that says the iterator needs to be
  >   implemented in the container."
- STL containers define those member types (`iterator`, `const_iterator`, etc) usually with type alias for some iterator category like `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` which defined as "A pointer to an element of an array satisfies all requirements of `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`".