# `iterator` and `const_iterator` are not required members of STL containers?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

Taken from [Understanding iterator/const_iterator implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59262424/understanding-iterator-const-iterator-implementation/59315923#59315923):

> "although `iterator` and `const_iterator` are types declared in the scope
>   of `vector`, there is no requirement that `vector`(or any STL container) have a member of either
>   type - `iterator` and `const_iterator` are part of the interface of
>   `std::vector` e.g. overloads of the member `begin()` returns those types,
>   but nothing is said about how those function obtain the iterator they
>   return"
>
> Additionally STL containers must have:
>
> "a begin and end function that returns iterators"

The above states that `iterator` and `const_iterator` are not required members of a STL container for example `vector`. I assume this means that the type returned from `.begin` or `.end` will differ based on implementation.

So I am wondering why this isn't problematic as I see a lot of people write out `std::vector<someType>::iterator` or `std::vector<someType>::const_iterator` where `iterator` and `const_iterator` are specified instead of using `auto` for example:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reading the quote wrong.  The person says

> have a member of either type

not

> have either type

When they say *have a member of either type* they mean there is no data member of type `iterator` or `const_iterator` in the class.

They do go on to say

> `iterator` and `const_iterator` are part of the interface of `std::vector`

Which is correct as the standard requires that `std::vector` surface these types in it interface.

Comment: but in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector, iterator and const_iterator are member types listed

Comment: @csguy In this case they mean member as an actual data member, not member like the standard considers a type alias in a class to be.

Comment: so iterator and const_iterator aren't "actual" members, they are type aliases in a container class and it is a requirement for a begin and end function to returns these aliases?

Comment: @csguy Correct. They are "member types" (aliases), they are not "members of type" (data members). They could be implemented in the container, or they could be implemented outside of the class and just referred to by the alias. It could also be that the alias refers to a plain pointer and that is the iterator used by the container.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` will normally contain a `typedef` (or equivalently, `using`) to specify the type that the name `iterator` will refer to. At its simplest, it might be something like:

```
template <class T, class Allocator>
class vector {
    using iterator = T *;
    using const_iterator = T const *;
    // ...
};
```

Likewise, its `begin` and `end` must return `iterator`s, and its `cbegin` and `cend` must return `const_iterator`s. But, the vector object doesn't (necessarily need to contain any objects of type `iterator` or `const_iterator`.

Also note that although the names `vector::iterator` and `vector::const_iterator` need to be defined, it isn't strictly necessary that they be defined by `vector` itself. You could (for example) have vector derive from a base class defines the appropriate names:

```
template <class T>
class vector_base {
public:
    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = T const *;
    // ...
};

template <class T, class Allocator>
class vector : public vector_base<T> {
};
```

So, even though `vector` itself doesn't define `iterator`, the name `vector::iterator` is well defined. I probably wouldn't bother to mention this except for one point: although it doesn't apply to `vector`, there is a standard class named `std::iterator`, that was intended primarily as a base class for iterators, and most of what it did was pretty much what's outlined above--define the member typedefs for `value_type`, `difference_type`, `reference`, and so on. Its use is now deprecated, but there are still a fair number of older iterator classes that used it (and older versions of the standard at least implied that most standard iterator types should use it as well).