# C++ - namespaces?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

In my class, we have been learning about the standard template library, and how you have to use `std::` when using objects from the library, so the compiler knows you are specifying the standard namespace. For example, `std::string` That's understandable. Recently though, I have been seeing objects and types specified with `string::`. What exactly does the `string::` mean? Is it part of some sort of string namespace? Why do you have to specify something that is already specified as part of the standard namespace, i.e the `std::string`. Also, where is the global namespace defined, and how does correlate with the standard namespace?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C++ need the scope resolution operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338217/why-does-c-need-the-scope-resolution-operator)

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the `::` refers to class members, e.g. `string::npos`.

It allows you to access static class members without creating an object.

It also allows you to access class members that have been overloaded by subclasses.

The global namespace is the default namespace.  It has no name, and it contains everything that is not explicitly placed inside a named namespace.