# How can i call base class functions from main with same signature?

Tags: c++, oop, c++14

In this question, I'm supposed to create 2 base classes `A` and `B`. Each of which contains a display function. There are 2 int inputs taken, the first one gets square and we find the root of the second. How do I code this in C++ ?

The question is :

1. Create a base class `A` and it contains a member function `display()` to calculate the square of a number and display it.
2. Create a base class `B` and it contains a member function `display()` to calculate the square root of a number and display it.
3. Create a class named `C` derived from `A` and `B`. Declare the object for class `C` and call the `display` functions of Class `A` and `B` from the main function to display the result.

Comment: `A::display()` and `B::display()`. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338217/why-does-c-need-the-scope-resolution-operator) like this :

```
class A {
public:
    void display() { std::cout << "A display" << std::endl; }
};
class B {
public:
    void display() { std::cout << "B display" << std::endl; }
};
class C : public A, public B
{
public :
    C() = default;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.B::display();
    c.A::display();

    return 0;
}
```

This way you declare manually which base class's `display` you want to call.