# Cannot use struct defined in another class even after using guards

Tags: c++, class, struct, compiler-errors

I am trying to use a struct of one class in another class. My first class looks like this:

## Class1.h

```c
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
    ~Class1();

    struct St{
        int x;
    }

    St struct1;

private:

};

#endif
```

Now in the header of the second class, I want to use this struct and variable.

## Class2.h

```c
#ifndef CLASS2_H
#define CLASS2_H

#include "Class1.h"

class Class2
{
public:

    Class2();
    ~Class2();

    St struct2;

private:

};
```

However, it says:

> identifier "St" is undefined.

When I use it this way:

```
Class1::St struct1;
```

the error goes away. What are the issues with my code?

Comment: You need to use `Class1::St` because `St` is nested inside `Class1`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338217/why-does-c-need-the-scope-resolution-operator

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Moving the definitiion of `St` outside `Class1` fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the issues with my code?

The issue is `St` is a nested class. Its fully qualified name is `::Class1::St1`. Within the scope of `Class2`, the unqualified name lookup does not use the scope of `Class1`, so no declaration of `St` will be found.

You can fix the issue by doing the following:

> When I use it this way:
>
> ```
> Class1::St struct1;
> ```
>
> the error goes away.